# Building `W[f_]:=w[t[f]]` out of solutions `w[t]`and `f[t]`of `NDSolve`

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am solving a system of ODEs with `NDSolve` to some initial condition and obtain two solutions `w[t]` and `f[t]` as `InterpolatingFunction`.

I am now trying to build `W[f_]:=w[t[f]]` and am failing to do so. The reason is, that I do not know how to obtain `t[f]` as function.

How can I do this? Or is there a smarter way to go about this?

Thanks for suggestions!

UPDATE: Following the comments so far here some additional information:

• @Kiro's comment: I actually tried to use inverse function before, but the inverse which Mathematica found would not be valid over the full domain of which it should / I would expect it too, and I was not sure how to fix this.

• @Alan's answer: Yes! What I am considering here is a perturbed Kepler problem. `t`is simply the time parameter, and `f` is what is called the true anomaly, i.e. the angle which a celestial object describes when orbiting another. So the mapping between `t` and `f` should be 1 to 1 and onto, unless I am missing something. But I plot `f[t]` it also looks as if it would be invertible.

• @march's answer: `ParametricPlot` worked like a charm, thank you so much!! This suffices for my current purposes, but for the future it would be really great to also know how to get the functional form. So if you have an idea how to do that, it would be great if you could share it.

I couldn't come up with a good minimal working example, so I thought I just copy in the full thing. I don't know how to make greek letters look the right way here, but copy-pasting the code into Mathematica works. The notebook can be executed top to bottom. What I put into different code boxes here should be put into different inputs in Mathematica.

Thanks again!

```
(* =============================================== *)
(*           I N I T I A L I S A T I O N           *)
(* =============================================== *)

(* fundamental constants in SI *)
c = 299792458;
G = 6.674 10^-11;

(* units -> SI *)
(* angles *)
deg = π/180;
amin = π/10800;
as = π/648000;
(* distances *)
au = 1.495978707 10^11;
pc = au/Tan[as];
mpc = 10^-3 pc;
(* Subscript[M, ⊙] from Kepler's 3^rd in SI *)

Ms = (4 π^2 au^3)/(G (365.25 24 60^2)^2);

(* mass parameters *)
m1 = 4.3 10^6 Ms; (* SBH *)
m2 = 0; (* S2 \[Rule] test particle *)
m = m1 + m2;
ν = 0; (* ν=(m1 m2)/m^2=0 for Subscript[m, 2]=0 (test particles) *)


(* initial orbital parameters *)
a0 = 5.03 mpc;
e0 = .883;
p0 = a0 (1 - e0^2);
i0 = 134.87 deg;
Ω0 = 226.53;
ω0 = 64.98;
f0 = 0;

t0 = 0;


(* perturbative acceleration *)
a[t_] := p[t]/(1 - e[t]^2);

R[t_] := FullSimplify[(G^2 m^2)/(
    c^2 a[t]^3 (1 - e[t]^2)^3) (1 + 
      e[t] Cos[f[t]])^2 (3 (e[t]^2 + 1) + 5 ν (1 - 7/10 e[t]^2) + 
      2 (e[t] - 4 ν) Cos[f[t]] - 
      4 e[t]^2 (1 - ν/8) Cos[f[t]]^2)];
S[t_] := FullSimplify[(G^2 m^2)/(c^2 a[t]^3 (1 - e[t]^2)^3)
     2 (2 - ν) (1 + e[t] Cos[f[t]])^3 e[t] Sin[f[t]]];
W[t_] := 0;


(* integration range *)
{ti, tf} = {0, 10 10^8};
```

```
(* =============================================== *)
(*              I N T E G R A T I O N              *)
(* =============================================== *)

(* integrate *)
    sol1 = Monitor[NDSolve[{
       p'[t] == 2 Sqrt[p[t]^3/(G m)] 1/(1 + e[t] Cos[f[t]]) S[t],
       e'[t] == Sqrt[p[t]/(G m)] (Sin[f[t]] R[t] + (2 Cos[f[t]] + e[t] (1 + Cos[f[t]]^2))/(1 + e[t] Cos[f[t]]) S[t]),
       ω'[t] == 1/e[t] Sqrt[p[t]/(G m)] (-Cos[f[t]] R[t] + (2 + e[t] Cos[f[t]])/(1 + e[t] Cos[f[t]]) Sin[f[t]] S[t]),
       f'[t] == Sqrt[(G m)/p[t]^3] (1 + e[t] Cos[f[t]])^2 + Sqrt[p[t]/(G m)] 1/e[t] (Cos[f[t]] R[t] - (2 + e[t] Cos[f[t]])/(1 + e[t] Cos[f[t]]) Sin[f[t]] S[t]),
       p[t0] == p0, e[t0] == e0, ω[t0] == ω0, f[t0] == f0,
       WhenEvent[f[t] == 2 π, "StopIntegration"]
      },
      {p, e, ω, f}, {t, ti, tf},
      EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])
     ], monitor]

{ti, tf} = sol1[[1, 1, 2]]["Domain"][[1]];
```

```
(* =============================================== *)
(*                    P L O T S                    *)
(* =============================================== *)

Plot[{Evaluate[ω[t] /. sol1] - ω0, Evaluate[ω[tf] /. sol1] - ω0},
  {t, ti, tf},
  PlotRange -> {{ti, tf}, {All, All}},
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
 ]
Plot[{Evaluate[f[t] /. sol1] - f0, Evaluate[f[tf] /. sol1] - f0},
  {t, ti, tf},
  PlotRange -> {{ti, tf}, {All, All}},
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
 ]
ParametricPlot[{{Evaluate[f[t] /. sol1][[1]] - f0, Evaluate[ω[t] /. sol1][[1]] - ω0},
  {Evaluate[f[t] /. sol1][[1]] - f0,Evaluate[ω[tf] /. sol1][[1]] - ω0}},
  {t, t0, tf},
  PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
 ]
```

Comment: I would start from `InverseFunction` but it's hard to say if that's enough since I don't know much about the expressions you are working with. Can you please provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Do you have a good reason to believe `f[t]` is invertible?

Comment: If all you want to do is plot, then you can do `ParametricPlot[{f[t], w[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}]`.  Alternatively, you can make a table of values `Table[{f[t], w[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax, tstep}]`. If you actually require the functional form, then you'll need to provide more details.

Comment: Hi @march, Alan and Kiro, thanks for your answers! I edited in my reaction to that in the start post (after UPDATE), and also provided the code to the problem.

Comment: The problem with getting a functional form is that there is no closed-form analytic  solution to the differential equation in the first place, which is why you're using `NDSolve` to begin with. So I'm not sure what you're looking for as far as that goes.

Comment: @march Thanks for the edits and answer! Sure, I do not mean an analytical closed form, but rather something like an ÌnterpolatingFunction`(IF). After all, `NDSolve` is able to provide me with IF for `w[t]` and `f[t]`. I am wondering how I could get an IF for `w[f]`. As you say, I could sample values, and then interpolate those again. But I am not sure if this is the best way to do it. I thought there must be a more straight forward way. Maybe I am mistaken.